# Applying transforms to tikz pics defined with named nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I have a tikz pic that I wish to rotate and move around. If I define the pic with number coordinates, this works fine. If I define the pic with named coordinates (handy reference points I use for many of my pics), then the transforms do not apply.

[image]

(err sorry, the picture is rather small. I guess because the default units are in centimetres?).

In the first example, I've defined a pic `named line` that goes from points (A) to (B).
In the example below it, I've defined a pic `unnamed line` that goes from points (0,0) to (1, 0) (which are A and B respectively).

I then apply a transform to the pic (`xscale=-1`). The named line is not transformed, while the unnamed one is.

I guess the coordinate definition of (A) and (B) is invariant to transforms? Is there a way to make them subject to the transforms? (I have quite a number of coordinates that I reuse a few times, and it would be nice to just to refer to them by labels instead of their numbers. I guess I can just `\def\coordA{(0,0)}` but I wanted to know if there was a Tikz solution).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\tikzset{
  named line/.pic = {
    \draw (A) -- (B);
  },
  unnamed line/.pic = {
    \draw (0,0) -- (1, 0);
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1, 0);

  \draw pic [red] {named line};
  \draw pic [blue,xscale=-1] {named line};

  \begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm] 
    \draw pic [red] {unnamed line};
    \draw pic [blue,xscale=-1] {unnamed line};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to note is that you can redefine `\coordinate`s at will, so one thing you might do is define the following command:

```
\newcommand\setcoordinates{
  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1, 0);
}
```

Then you can say `\setcoordinates` every time you need `(A)` and `(B)` to be transformed. Tikz coordinates are not supposed to be transformed. If you really want to transform them anyways, though, the following code defines a key `transform coordinates` that changes the way `tikz` looks up the coordinates of nodes in order to accomplish this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@calc@anchor@modified#1.#2\tikz@stop{%
  \bgroup
  \pgftransformreset
  \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{#1}}{#2}%
  \edef\tikz@point@smuggle{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}%
  \expandafter\egroup
  \tikz@point@smuggle
}

\tikzset{transform coordinates/.code={\let\tikz@calc@anchor\tikz@calc@anchor@modified}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);

  \draw (A) circle [radius=10pt];

\draw[xshift=1cm,red] (A) circle [radius=10pt];
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[transform coordinates]
  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);

  \draw (A) circle [radius=10pt];

\draw[xshift=1cm,red] (A) circle [radius=10pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0, 0);

\draw (A) circle [radius=10pt];

\draw[xshift=1cm,red,transform coordinates] (A) circle [radius=10pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ahh, I had thought it was specific to the use of `pic` somehow. Thanks.

Comment: Oh right, so if you want your `pic` to make use of this, you should say `\tikzset{named line/.pic = {\draw[transform coordinate] (A) -- (B);}`. This should do exactly what you want.