# How to move tikzpicture with named nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-pic

I am trying to position an image with rounded corners to a specific position on screen. However, according to [the following post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180665/tikz-xshift-not-shifting), *yshift* and *xshift* do not affect nodes that are named and I am still a bit confused on how to use the `++` and if this is the best approach.

Take my current situation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip [rounded corners=0.7cm] (0,0) rectangle coordinate (centerpoint) (4,4.0cm); 
        \node [inner sep=0pt] at (centerpoint) {\includegraphics[width=4.0cm]{dogesmall.jpg}}; 

        \draw[line width=0.08cm,rounded corners=0.7cm] (0,0) rectangle (4,4.0cm);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

*(Where "dogesmall.jpg" is my current image)*

This produces a result that places the image in the upper left hand corner, as defined by the margins. However, I would like to tweak the position of the *tikzpicture* without changing the margins like so:

[image: Babou]

**How would I go about accomplishing such a task?**

I tried following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343139/applying-transforms-to-tikz-pics-defined-with-named-nodes) by using the following:

```
\newcommand\setcoordinates{
    \coordinate (centerpoint) at (4,4.0cm);
}
```

And then referencing this coordinate by `\coordinate (centerpoint)` and then applying a `shift` transformation, but that does not work either. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you looking for `overlay`, which allows you to position stuff at absolute coordinates?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \begin{scope}
        \clip [rounded corners=0.7cm] (current page text area.north west) coordinate (centerpoint)  rectangle ++(4,-4); 
        \node [inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] at (centerpoint) 
        {\includegraphics[width=4.0cm,height=4cm]{example-image-duck}}; 
    \end{scope}
        \draw[line width=0.08cm,rounded corners=0.7cm] (centerpoint)  rectangle ++(4,-4); 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to place the image at the upper left corner of the page (rather than the upper left corner of the of the text area), replace `(current page text area.north west)` by `(current page.north west)`.

**ADDENDUM**: This is a version that shifts the picture relative to the current position in the text, which is set using `\tikzmark` that comes with the `tikzmark` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tikzmark{x}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \begin{scope}
        \clip [rounded corners=0.7cm] ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=2cm]pic cs:x) coordinate (centerpoint)  rectangle ++(4,-4); 
        \node [inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] at (centerpoint) 
        {\includegraphics[width=4.0cm,height=4cm]{example-image-duck}}; 
    \end{scope}
        \draw[line width=0.08cm,rounded corners=0.7cm] (centerpoint)  rectangle ++(4,-4); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This produces the following error: `Package pgf Error: No shape named current page text area is known.` In addition, is the only way to *tweak* the position (i.e. not just using an anchor) to change the `++(4,-4)`?

Comment: Using `Northwest` is called an anchor. It anchors the picture in the northwest corner. I was seeking to move the picture just *slightly* up and to the left, not necessarily to the exact corner. A `shift` would be perfect, but I am not allowed to do such an action. Does that make sense?

Comment: I can compile with no errors with `(current page.north west)`, but having `(current page text area.north west)` produces the error. And I am using the latex compile on www.overleaf.com. Lastly, can you give an example with `tikzmark`?